# Overriding construct

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture

Lets say I have this code:

```
abstract class AbstractCar {
    private $car;

    public function __construct(CarInterface $car)
    {
        $this->car = $car;
    }
}

class LamboCar extends AbstractCar {
    public function __construct(LamboCarInterface $car)
    {
        parent::__construct($car);
    }
}
```

Question is: is overriding construct method only to change `$car` type from `CarInterface` to `LamboCarInterface` (`LamboCarInterface` extends `CarInterface`) bad practice? Let's say AbstractCar do call some methods from `CarInterface`, and `LamboCar` call some methods from `LamboCarInterface`

Comment: Make your `LamboCarInterface` to inherit `CarInterface` and your `__construct` should receive `CarInterface`. No, it's not a bad practice. It's ok

Comment: It already inherit `CarInterface`. Lets say the main purpose of overriding construct with `LamboCarInterface`, is that lambo has some methods which are used in `LamboCar`, and to extort type of given object. (`LamboCar` can't receive `CarInterface`)